# Array of arrays and shared memory

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am creating a nested array. When I build a new row and append it to the nested array, clear the row using the method `clear`, and start over building another new row, it clears the row in both arrays. Any idea why?

code snippet:

```
new_rec = Array.new
new_rec << "string1"
new_rec << "string2"
new_rec << "string3"
new_rec << "string4"

new_csv = Array.new
new_csv << new_rec
new_rec.clear
new_csv #=> [[]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have `new_rec` in `new_csv`, and you cleared the object `new_rec`.

Comment: Okay, how else can I get the data into new_csv as an array within new_csv?

Comment: Don't `clear` the row, but construct a new one each time. You can keep using the same variable name for different rows.